# How to send mail via a python script if MFA is enabled for that mail account?

Tags: python, django

I am not able to send mail through python script if MFA is enabled for my account.

Comment: How are you trying to send it? Share code if you have for doing so. Also, you have added django as tag to this question. Check this out, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/

Comment: when MFA was disabled on my mail account, i was able to send mail through python script using smtplib, when i enable it but now i am not able to send.
Code:
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
smtpObj.login(MailFrom, MailBoxPAss, initial_response_ok=True)

error msg (When MFA is enabled):

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [FR2P281CA0032.DEUP281.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')

Comment: Check in your account settings you may have an option for allowing an application sign-in. The idea is to allow a third-party application for which the mail provider can generate an application password that can be used. Check this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 . It's for gmail, but you can definitely get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for you response!!
But still not able to do.

Comment: Still getting authentication related error?

Comment: to send mail we need to login through python code and when we login there should be a push command which will help to send otp or some approval kind of thing on MFA device, through which there approval only we will be able to login and send mail